# R: Reconstructing a logistic regression model with splines using published coefficients and spline knots

Tags: r, logistic, prediction, regression-coefficients

**What I would like to do**

I would like to reconstruct a logistic regression model with splines (*Lymph Node Involvement (Cores)*) using published coefficients and spline knots. All sources that I posted here are from: https://www.mskcc.org/nomograms/prostate/pre_op/coefficients

**Why I would like to do that**

My aim is to reconstruct the model "Lymph node involment (Cores)" in R, so that I can apply it on a large number of patients of a clinical study (without having to type all the data in an online calculator for every subject) and predict their probability of Lymph node involvement.

**The published information about the model**

The model definition is as follows:

[image]

The restricted cubic spline terms are as follows:

[image]
[image]

The intercept and coefficients are as follow:
[image]

**Question**

1. Is it possible to reconstruct this model with the published data
2. If yes, how can this be achieved using R

**What I have already done**

I found following source, however, it is slightly different (I do not want to change anything of the model)
[Reconstructing a logistic regression model from literature using published coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436207/reconstructing-a-logistic-regression-model-from-literature-using-published-coeff)

I understand that I somehow have to reconstruct the model with something like:

```
#reconstruct model
copylogit <- ...
```

And then apply it to my data:

```
#make test data
newdata <-data.frame(age=as.numeric(80),psa=as.numeric(10),gleason_grade=as.factor(4),clinical_stage=as.character("2A"), no_of_positive_cores=as.numeric(2),no_of_negativ_cores=as.numeric(10))

#apply model to test data
predict(copylogit, newdata = newdata, type = "response")
```

And the expected result for this example would be: 17%

**Update:**
Since I am not sure if it is possible to reconstruct the model with the published data I thought about to generate a prediction equation so that I can calculate the probabilites of lymph node involvement in a larger dataset. Therefore, I opened a new question: [Calculate spline terms of a logistic regression using published knots and formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491100/calculate-spline-terms-of-a-logistic-regression-using-published-knots-and-formul)

Comment: I see the formulation of a task, 'reconstruct a prediction curve based on published coefficients', but I believe that you missed stating your question related to it. What is the question?

Comment: Pardon me! I added the questions

Comment: What do you mean by "reconstruct"? Is it different from "to generate a prediction equation" and what you did in the other question?

Comment: Thx for your patience. It is actually my goal to compare the model's performance with another model's performance in a validation cohort. To do so I wanted to calculate the probabilities for both models and compare them using the c-index. Since I learned that this is a power procedure, I thought about to compare the models using a likelihood test. With my very limited understanding I thought that I could re-fit both models to my data (this is what I meant by reconstruct) and then compare both models (i.e. glm objects) in R. If this makes any sense (I doubt that), I can add it to the question.